# Showing data on frontend from sql databases using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, frontend, djongo

For fetching data from databases, I usually see people create a class in `models.py` and they migrate it, and then they fetch data from databases and show it on the front-end.
my question is, **i already have a database which has `student_info` table and has lots of data.**
**I don't want to define `student_info` class in `models.py` and do migration. Instead, since i already have `student_info` data in `sql database`. so I want to fetch it directly. can i do so?**

one method i know of doing the same, is directly connecting sql server in `views.py` as;

```
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="******",database=database_name)
```

and fetching the data and passing it as `variable` in `index.html`. But the problem is, it fetches data only once, and if i refresh the page where local server is running, all the content will disappear, and server will report `Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 59579)` and to see the data, again i need to restart the sever.

**Kindly looking for a better approach to show data on front-end from the existing databases**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is a simple thing for the solution.

Create a StudentData(models.Model) class which will store your data in them as model objects And define all the attributes/ columns in models according to the data and which is in the student_info table.

Write a simple script ( using pymysql ) to retrive all the data from the student_table , store it in text file . ( This part is easy )

take that text file and now in your django project , run a shell command or create a new script to transfer the text_file student data to model objects and save them  .
Now you have your data .

I think this will work fine .
If you also want code . I'll include it.

The code for the solution :

An Update : I have used pymysql for this scripts , i think mysqlconnector will also do the work.

Create a folder inside your project named "Creating Database model" ( you can choose whatever you want but I created the files and all script inside this folder )

first_file : "data retreiving.py"

```
import pymysql as psql
import os
connection = psql.connect(
    user = "root" , 
    password = os.environ.get("MYSQL_PASSWORD") , 
    database = "college" ,    
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from student") ;
data_text_file = open("Creating Database model/text_data.txt" , "w")

for row in cursor :
    temp_string = ""
    for data in row :
        temp_string+= "{} ".format(str(data)) 
    data_text_file.write(temp_string+"\n")
data_text_file.close()
```

Enter your password for connection. Here I am using college database which has student table with some student data .
Then I am creating a file text_data.txt which will have the text data of the table .
I used string formatting here for convinence and better retrival of data on the other side.

My student table schema has five fields :
id , first_name, last_name , age , branch

so my models.py according to this database is here . You create your own according to your requirement.

```
from django.db import models

class StudentData(models.Model) :
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , required = True)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , required = True)
    age        = models.IntegerField(max_length = 100 , required = True)
    branch     = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , required = True)
    
    def __str__(self) :
        return "{} {}".format(first_name , last_name)
```

second file : "data entry in models.py"

This file takes data and then saves it to the model . And you get your database in django .

```
with open("Creating Database model/text_data.txt") as f :
    data = f.read()
    
new_data_list = []

data = data.split("\n")
new_data_list = []
for i in data :
    temp_list = i.split(" ")[:-1]
    new_data_list.append(temp_list)
data = new_data_list[:-1]

for i in data :
    student_info = StudentModel(
        first_name = i[1] , 
        last_name = i[2] ,
        age = i[3] ,
        branch = i[4] 
    )
    studnet_info.save()
```

These all are within the "Creating Database model" folder.

This will do all the work you require. Make sure to debug and understand before committing to database.

Comment: Thank you so such, i will request you to please write the code too especially for the last part. And also i think your solution will work, but restoring the data will consume additional memory and also suppose if we are working with mongodb instead of mysql then again mongodb being Nosql we can't define all the attributes in class StudentData(models.Model)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Included the code. Run it . Also I have not worked with nosql database before . I could not help you with that .

Comment: This is a valid solution, but maybe try first the [Django legacy database integration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/). If this does **NOT** work, you can go that road...

Comment: Thanks for recommending this solution. I didn't know about this. Thanks

Comment: @OmKashyap Thank you so much for your kind answer, i got to learn a lot from you. We can do what you suggested.

Comment: @OmKashyap may you please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862269/hide-and-show-elements-inside-django-html-template